# What's the difference between delete and assign element in python?

Tags: python

I'm wondering which method is better if I want to refresh a value.

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
```

If I want to change refresh the value of the list.

One way is `myList[2] = 5`

And another way is

```
del myList[2]
myList[2] = 5
```

The element in list is some objects and will be refreshed frequently.
So when will the element really be deleted in first method and which method
is a betther one?

Comment: Did you actually try this?  Your second version doesn't work, so that's probably not a good choice.

Comment: You can not assign a value a list item that does no longer exist...makes no sense. Downvote for making a claim/question that the OP did not verify himself in advance....unnecessary noise here.

Comment: Sorry, the second method is a mistake. I meant to use myList.append(5). I wanted to ask when will the old data in myList[2] really be deleted in first method. Sorry for the noise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct is `myList[2] = 5`

but this code will genrate exception:

```
>>> del myList[2]
>>> myList
[1, 2]
>>> myList[2] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

when you do `del myList[2]`, `myList` becomes of length 2, so max index is `1` and by doing `myList[2] = 5` you are trying to insert at location that is not exist.(overrun problem)

You may have *second choice* like this

```
>>> del myList[2]
>>> myList
[1, 2]
>>> myList.append(5); 
>>>  myList
[1, 2, 5]
```

But if you just want to refresh a value.*on existing index* then first choice that is `myList[2] = 5` is good and simple. Where as if you wants to append at last (*index not exists*) then use append().

Answer (score 0):

The element in the first method is never really deleted, it's value is merely changed (meaning it points to a different object/value).

The second method is not valid Python at all, as after you deleted `mylist[2]`, mylist would only have 2 elements in it, and `mylist[2]` wouldn't exist anymore. Even if you deleted an element in the middle of the list, you would still be changing the wrong value, and you would need slicing to reassign it. See below:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
mylist[1] = 4
print(mylist)
# [1, 4, 3]

del mylist[1]
print(mylist)
# [1, 3]

mylist[1] = 0
print(mylist)
# [1, 0]
```

Conclusion: Use the first method, as it is by far the simplest, and doesn't cause you trouble (like the second method).

Answer (score 0):

The first only changes the place where python looks for the value...

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> id(mylist[2]) # check location
31108776
>>> mylist[2] = 5 # change the value
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 5]         # the value has changed
>>> id(mylist[2])
31108752          # location has also changed
```

Also, 2nd generates an exception

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]  
>>> del mylist[2]  
>>> mylist[2] = 5  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module> 
    mylist[2] = 5  
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

And you can not assign a value a list item that does no longer exist as the item is deleted.